# Java Script DOMException Web Audio API audioContext.createMediaElementSource call again the function

Tags: javascript

Hi everyone i need yours apreciated help 
i have the next function, this work the first time to press button , but i press again button  the audio no work.
 the console  log is this: Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'createMediaElementSource' on 'BaseAudioContext': HTMLMediaElement already connected previously to a different MediaElementSourceNode.
    at cargar_audio1

¿How can solved this and load the video every time press button?

the code i use is this:

```
 document.getElementById('audio1').addEventListener('click', function() {
 var mediaElement1 = document.getElementById("ad1"); 
 mediaElement1.src = "audio1.mp3";
 load_audio1();
 });


 var analyser, source;
 function load_audio1() {
 var audio1 = document.getElementById('ad1');
 var audioContext = new AudioContext();
 analyser = audioContext.createAnalyser();
 analyser.minDecibels = -60;
 analyser.maxDecibels = -10;  
 analyser.fftSize = 32;
 source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(audio1);
 source.connect(analyser);
 analyser.connect(audioContext.destination); 
 audio1.play();
 view_dat_audio();
 }
```

Comment: define  var audioContext = new AudioContext(); outside the click event and the function load_audio1()

Comment: Tanks Marouen Mhiri   but no work :(

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "load the video every time press button" means that you want to play the audio-file audio1.mp3 each time the click-event on `audio1` is fired, you could do the following:

In order to play the file you need to do two Things:

1. Initialize the Audio-Graph (creating the analyzer-node and connecting it to an Audio-source etc.)
2. call play() on the graph

Right now you are doing this in one step in `load_audio1()` The solution is to separate the initialization and the call to `play()` and do the initialization only once in the beginning when it is nessecary.

Roughly like this:

```
document.getElementById('audio1').addEventListener('click', clickHandler);

function clickHandler() {
    if (!audioGraphIsInitialized()) {
        initAudioGraph();
    }

    audio1.play();
}
```

Comment: how can conect audio file  wit analyser ?

Comment: or other option to listen to any sound in the browser

Comment: I've updated the answer. This should show the principle, you just need to move your code from above to the function `initAudioGraph()` without the call to `play()` and create a new function `audioGraphIsInitialzed()` which tests whether `initAudioGraph()` has already been called or not.

Comment: thanks to try what I suggest, for the moment I had to try it in an unorthodox way with iframes that recharge the page XD